# Cannot see PiHole clients on Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

Dears

I am running PiHole on Docker Swarm but I only see 2 clients: 10.0.0.3 and localhost.
If I understood correctly from various discussion over the web, I should be able to see all the clients in PiHole if I expose the DNS ports with Host mode (pihole is forced to run on a single swarm node) in this way:

```
 ports:
      - published: 53
        target: 53
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - published: 53
        target: 53
        protocol: udp
        mode: host
      - published: 67
        target: 67
        protocol: udp
        mode: ingress
      - published: 8053
        target: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
```

Unfortunately, if I expose ports in this way, the dns service does not work anymore: I can see the port exposed on the container:

```
pi@raspy3:~ $ docker port 3be0321961a6
53/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:53
53/udp -> 0.0.0.0:53
```

but i cannot see them with NETSTAT:

```
pi@raspy3:~ $ netstat -atu | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8053               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8000               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9000               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2377               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7946               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

and nslookup does not work:

```
pi@raspy4:~ $ nslookup google.com 192.168.32.2
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Could you help me understanding what I am loosing, please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing the *Interface Listening Behaviour* to *Listen on all interfaces, permit all origins*.

Obviously be sure to follow all the security points from the PiHole's team ;)